# Android MediaCodec & MediaExtractor For video and audio playing

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I'm new here and fresh to Android development. Here is my first question here.

I'm using `MediaExtractor` and `MediaCodec` to play `mp4` file, with video and audio. Now I get one pair of extractor/codec for video and another pair of extractor/codec for audio, realized in two separate threads.

My question is: can I use just one extractor with two codecs to play video and audio synchronously?

If yes, How to do it? When I used extractor.selecttrack for one, the other won't work...

Thanks a lot.

Thanks to everyone's answer here. I have figure this out. I made a mistake that the extractor can only select one track. Actually, you can select more than one track, and extractor.advance() will read each track at one time subsequently.

Comment: Why don't you just use a MediaPlayer? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: @KenWolf. bcz I need to design my own player with more features that MediaPlayer does not have.

Comment: In your question, you said 'extractor.selecttrack` doesn't work for other track. Can you please elaborate on what didn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's answer here. I have figure this out. I made a mistake that the extractor can only select one track. Actually, you can select more than one track, and extractor.advance() will read each track at one time subsequently.

Comment: Can you please paste sample code here? I also have the same issue and trying to fix for more than a day. Kindly paste your sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should use just one extractor, and one MediaCodec instance per track.

You shoudldn't use MediaExtractor.selectTrack in this case, you should just read the packets from all tracks, and for each packet returned choose which MediaCodec to pass it to.

Comment: How to realize the player like this? I mean play video and audio synchronously. Thank.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify that you shouldn't use selectTrack in this case.

Comment: @mstorsjo how to choose the ByteBuffer for readSampleData? It should be the input buffer of one of the codecs, but we can't know in advance if it will be a video packet or an audio packet...

Comment: You can call getSampleTrackIndex() or any other method to get information about the current sample before you call readSampleData(). It's only once you call advance() that the extractor moves on to the next sample.